# how to insert datagridview rows into sql when datagridview has some specific criteria in specific cell?

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to add all datagridview rows in sql database which has specific text "orange" but when i add it gives me error that supid is not provided.can someone guide me. my datagrid is look like

[image]

enter code here

Private Sub orange()

```
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("server= .\SQLEXPRESS; database = software; integrated security=true")
            Using cmd5 As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO orangedata (supid,date,docno,name,qty,value) VALUES (@supid,@date,@docno,@name,@qty,@value)", cn)
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@supid", SqlDbType.NChar)
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@docno", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                cmd5.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows

                With cmd5
                    If rw.Cells(0).Value = "Orange" Then
                        .Parameters("@supid").Value = combobox6.text
                        .Parameters("@date").Value = Now.ToString
                        .Parameters("@docno").Value = Val(Label5.Text)
                        .Parameters("@name").Value = rw.Cells(7).Value
                        .Parameters("@qty").Value = rw.Cells(8).Value
                        .Parameters("@value").Value = rw.Cells(1).Value
                    End If
                End With
                cn.Open()
                cmd5.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cn.Close()
            Next
        End Using 
        End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of combobox6.text when the error is thrown. Also the code is finding the cells with first column of Gold, not Orange.  Also, what is the datasource of the DataGridView as you are probably working on the datasource directly, rather than the datagridview that's displaying it.

Comment: combobox6.text  = 1 and i am adding values from textboxes to datagridview. i have corrected orange instead of gold. it is still giving error (@supid nchar(4000),@date varchar(8000),@docno varchar(8000),@or' expects the parameter '@supid', which was not supplied.

Comment: Hello, if by chance the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn uses a DataTable for it's DataSource with DisplayMember, ValueMember,DataPropertyName set and the DataGridView has a DataTable setup using two BindingSource to glue together the DataTable contains for the DataGridView and the DataGridViewComboBoxColum I can present logic to work with not touching the DataGridView to get rows you are after in a conceptual example.